# How can I prevent mobilenetv3 from overfitting with less data?

Tags: deep-learning, image-classification, pytorch, computer-vision

So I have around 462 images and I can't really get more images. I am using a pretrained model of MobileNetV3 with the respective weights. I am facing a huge problem of overfitting and no real solution to it. I have not personally used mobilenet as much but I am looking into it as I need to implement it into a device since it is lightweight.

I have tried dropout with weight decay and learning rate. Additionally, I have used gaussion noise as well. But no difference whatsoever. Could this be a data problem or a model issue?

Additionally, I got a test accuracy as 88% but I don't think that translated into anything as the images were mostly missclassified.

[image]

This is my code so far:

````
# Set the random seed for reproducibility
random.seed(42)

IMG_WIDTH = 232
IMG_HEIGHT = 232


class AddGaussianNoise(object):
    def __init__(self, mean=0.0, std=1.0):
        self.std = std
        self.mean = mean

    def __call__(self, tensor):
        return tensor + torch.randn(tensor.size()) * self.std + self.mean

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.__class__.__name__ + "(mean={0}, std={1})".format(
            self.mean, self.std
        )


# Define the data transformation
transform = transforms.Compose(
    [
        transforms.Resize(
            (IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH), interpolation=Image.BILINEAR
        ),  # Resize the images
        # transforms.CenterCrop(224),  # Crop the images to 224x224 about the center
        transforms.ToTensor(),  # Convert the image to PyTorch Tensor data type
        transforms.Normalize(
            mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]
        ),  # Normalize the images
        # AddGaussianNoise(0.0, 2.0),
    ]
)

# Load the dataset
dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root="real_data/", transform=transform)
test_dataset = datasets.ImageFolder(root="test-set/", transform=transform)

print(len(dataset))

# Split the dataset into training and validation sets
train_size = 0.7
val_size = 0.3
train_len = int(len(dataset) * train_size)
print(train_len)
val_len = len(dataset) - train_len
print(val_len)

train_dataset, val_dataset = torch.utils.data.random_split(
    dataset, [train_len, val_len]
)

# Create the training and validation dataloaders
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=True)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=False)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=16, shuffle=False)

# Define the loss function
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

model = models.mobilenet_v3_large(
    pretrained=True, weights="MobileNet_V3_Large_Weights.IMAGENET1K_V2", dropout=0.3
)

model.eval()

# Define the optimizer as Adam with weight decay correction
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0001, weight_decay=0.0001)
# scheduler = optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=10, gamma=0.1)

train_loss = []
train_accuracy = []
val_loss = []
val_accuracy = []

# Define the early stopping criteria
patience = 20
min_delta = 0.001
best_val_loss = float("inf")
counter = 0


def train_epoch(epoch):
    start_time = time.time()

    # Train the model for one epoch
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        # Forward pass
        outputs = model(images)

        # Calculate the loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

        # Backward pass
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        # Update the parameters
        optimizer.step()

        # Calculate the accuracy
        correct = (outputs.argmax(1) == labels).sum()
        accuracy = correct / len(labels)

        # Add the loss and accuracy to the lists
        train_loss.append(loss.item())
        train_accuracy.append(accuracy)

    end_time = time.time()
    return end_time - start_time


def test_accuracy(model, test_loader):
    model.eval()
    correct = 0
    total = 0

    with torch.no_grad():
        for images, labels in test_loader:
            outputs = model(images)
            _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

    accuracy = correct / total
    return accuracy


for epoch in range(60):
    # Train the model
    train_time = train_epoch(epoch)

    # Validate the model
    with torch.no_grad():
        total_val_loss = 0
        total_val_accuracy = 0
        total_samples = 0

        for images, labels in val_loader:
            outputs = model(images)

            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            correct = (outputs.argmax(1) == labels).sum()
            accuracy = correct / len(labels)

            total_val_loss += loss.item() * len(labels)
            total_val_accuracy += accuracy.item() * len(labels)
            total_samples += len(labels)

        val_loss.append(total_val_loss / total_samples)
        val_accuracy.append(total_val_accuracy / total_samples)

        # if val_loss[-1] < best_val_loss - min_delta:
        #     best_val_loss = val_loss[-1]
        #     counter = 0
        #     # Save the model checkpoint
        #     torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model4.pth")
        # else:
        #     counter += 1
        #     if counter >= patience:
        #         print("Early stopping")
        #         break

    # Print the loss and accuracy
    print(
        f"Epoch {epoch + 1}: Train Loss {train_loss[-1]}, Train Accuracy {train_accuracy[-1]}, Val Loss {val_loss[-1]}, Val Accuracy {val_accuracy[-1]}, Train Time {train_time}"
    )

test_acc = test_accuracy(model, test_loader)
print(f"Test Accuracy: {test_acc}")

# Save the model
torch.save(model.state_dict(), "model4.pth")
```
````